# Как мне поставить Drawable в указанную точку на экране?

Tags: java, android

Как мне поставить `Drawable` в указанную точку на экране в Android?
Допустим, у вас есть фигура круг и вы хотите ее установить программно в указанные координаты экрана. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

1. Берём канву сцены.
2. [Рисуем](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176441/drawable-image-on-a-canvas) на ней Drawable.

   ```
   Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foobar);
   d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
   d.draw(canvas);
   ```

[Подробный мануал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/drawable.php), какой `Drawable` взять за основу.

Или помещаем любой canvas-содержащий объект с отрисованным `Drawable` на сцену как потомка, а потом в него отрисовываем (`Bitmap`).

Игрострой: [Пишем движок игры под Android](http://davidmd.ru/2011/08/23/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android-%E2%80%93-tutorial-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-5-surface/)

Конкретно про круг вопрос [уже был тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954596/how-to-draw-circle-by-canvas-in-android)

Ниже - репост из ссылки:

**MyActivity.java**:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
{
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      ...
      setContentView(new MyView(this,w,h));
   }

}
```

**View.java**:

```
public class MyView extends SurfaceView
{
    public MyView(Context context, int w, int h)
    {
        super(context);
        Canvas grid = new Canvas(Bitmap.createBitmap(h,w, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
        grid. drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        grid.drawCircle(w/2, h/2 , w/2, paint);
    }
}
```

Что делаем, чтобы не получать чёрный экран без прорисовки:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 super.onDraw(canvas);

 canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно через `Canvas` делать:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(100, 0);
drawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```